# Substitute specific letters in document with spans

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have the following HTML code

```
<div class="answers">
  He<b>y</b> <span class='doesntmatter'>eve</span>ryone
</div>
```

And I have the following array:

```
['correct','correct','incorrect','correct','correct','correct','incorrect','incorrect','correct','correct','incorrect']
```

I want to transform this piece of HTML code, and add a span to each letter with the class  in the array (I'll explain)

So, I want to transform the letter H to say `<span class='correct'>H</span>`

e to say: `<span class='correct'>e</span>`

y to say: `<span class='incorrect'>y</span>`

e to say: `<span class='correct'>e</span>`

And so on. I want to make sure to keep the original HTML, `<br>` tags, `<p>` tags and the such. I can't use jQuery(element).text() for this reason (since it breaks the tags).

Anyone has an idea how I would do this? It's much appreciated.

Comment: Did you take a look to the .wrap() method? http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: You might want to check out [LetteringJS](http://letteringjs.com/) by the inimitable Dave Rupert, at least to steal the (fairly simple) code.

Comment: please read the rules, you should post specific problems that are reproducible. this is a code request.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr =  ['correct','correct','incorrect','correct','correct','correct','incorrect','incorrect','correct','correct','incorrect'],
    answer = document.getElementsByClassName("answers")[0],
    rex = /(?=\w|<)(?=[^>]*(?:<|$))/,
    i = 0, class;

answer.innerHTML = answer.innerHTML.split(rex).map(function(p) {
    if (p.indexOf('>')) return p;
    class = arr[i++] || 'notDefined';
    return '<span class="' + class + '">' + p + '</span>';
}).join('');
```

Non-word characters are not wrapped. If the text contains html-entities (e.g `&nbsp;`) there will be some extra effort.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

http://jsfiddle.net/bn777pky/

The jQuery needs refined but it's not my strong suit.

**HTML**

```
<div class="numbers">123456789</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.correct { 
  color: red
}
.incorrect {
  color: blue;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$(".numbers").each(function (index) {

var characters = $(this).text().split("");

$this = $(this);
$this.empty();
$.each(characters, function (i, el) {

    $this.append("<span>" + el + "</span");  

});

$("span").each( function (index) {
      index += 1;

      if(index % 3 == 0) {
        $(this).addClass("incorrect");
      }
      else {
        $(this).addClass("correct");
      }
 });

});
```

Comment: Nice try, but he specifically points out that there is html within the answer.  This will strip it, as the OP already pointed out.  Also, you could have done it in one `each()` rather than 2 ;)